# Architecture not supported error when installing OpenSSL on OS X

Tags: ios, xcode, makefile, openssl, rbenv

`rbenv-2.6.5` is attempting to install `openssl-1.1.1d` and that's where the architecture error comes, I have no direct access to the Makefile:

```
$ rbenv install 2.6.5
Downloading openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/1e3a91bc1f9dfce01af26026f856e064eab4c8ee0a8f457b5ae30b40b8b711f2
Installing openssl-1.1.1d...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.1 using ruby-build 20191124)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/8s/8mw7vg315l7dr9vyfxmv9vk80000gn/T/ruby-build.20191126132843.6027.Z0Hvfg
Results logged to /var/folders/8s/8mw7vg315l7dr9vyfxmv9vk80000gn/T/ruby-build.20191126132843.6027.log

Last 10 log lines:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:243:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/inttypes.h:227:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_wchar_t.h:34:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wchar_t'
typedef __darwin_wchar_t wchar_t;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [apps/app_rand.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Complete log:

```
$ cat /var/folders/8s/8mw7vg315l7dr9vyfxmv9vk80000gn/T/ruby-build.20191126132843.6027.log
/var/folders/8s/8mw7vg315l7dr9vyfxmv9vk80000gn/T/ruby-build.20191126132843.6027.Z0Hvfg ~/Developer/ReactNativeApp/ios
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 8845861
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2019 09:50:32 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Oct 2019 21:38:26 GMT
ETag: "3be209000dbc7e1b95bcdf47980a3baa"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 e56e6732f380db727425bac2d6158761.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: FRA2-C2
X-Amz-Cf-Id: Hw-jhD36n4Jk8CezqbAuFTzudNo4qopXkdH3CaxRXUHbadZgf9Z6xA==
Age: 9492

/var/folders/8s/8mw7vg315l7dr9vyfxmv9vk80000gn/T/ruby-build.20191126132843.6027.Z0Hvfg/openssl-1.1.1d /var/folders/8s/8mw7vg315l7dr9vyfxmv9vk80000gn/T/ruby-build.20191126132843.6027.Z0Hvfg ~/Developer/ReactNativeApp/ios
Operating system: x86_64-apple-darwinDarwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1d (0x1010104fL) for darwin64-x86_64-cc
Using os-specific seed configuration
Creating configdata.pm
Creating Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL file first)         ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
WARNING! If you wish to build 32-bit libraries, then you have to
         invoke 'KERNEL_BITS=32 ./config  '--prefix=/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/openssl' '--openssldir=/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/openssl/ssl' 'zlib-dynamic' 'no-ssl3' 'shared''.
/usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
        "-oMakefile" crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h.in > crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
/usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
        "-oMakefile" crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h.in > crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
/usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
        "-oMakefile" include/openssl/opensslconf.h.in > include/openssl/opensslconf.h
make depend && make _all
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/include -MMD -MF apps/app_rand.d.tmp -MT apps/app_rand.o -c -o apps/app_rand.o apps/app_rand.c
In file included from apps/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
In file included from ./e_os.h:13:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include/limits.h:37:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from apps/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
In file included from ./e_os.h:13:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include/limits.h:37:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from apps/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
In file included from ./e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:243:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/inttypes.h:226:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from apps/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
In file included from ./e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:243:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/inttypes.h:226:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
note: '__int128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
In file included from apps/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
In file included from ./e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:243:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/inttypes.h:226:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
        ^
note: '__uint128_t' declared here
In file included from apps/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
In file included from ./e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:243:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/inttypes.h:227:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_wchar_t.h:34:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wchar_t'
typedef __darwin_wchar_t wchar_t;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [apps/app_rand.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two errors in total, the final solution was:

1. Made sure I have the right version of `gcc` installed
2. Install `xcode-select` to fix the compiler error by selecting the right environment:

   `xcode-select --install`

   `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`
3. Restarted Mac (important)
4. Installed the rbenv:

   `rbenv install 2.6.5`